# Automatically wrap text with smartparen

Tags: smartparens

Using smartparen, if I have some text I can select it then press
`(` `{` or `[` and the text is wrapped in those braces. How can I extend this functionality so that (in Latex for example) if I press `$` the text is wrapped in `$...$` or if I press `"` the text is wrapped in LaTeX quotes. Can it also be done with two letter pairs like `\(` ?

I feel that this is straightforward, but I haven't been able to get it working with `sp-local-pair` and couldn't find a similar question.

Comment: You can use `sp-wrap-with-pair`